# Bash Script Empty Argument Testing

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to write a simple script with the following logic: IF the first argument is a valid regular file, run the for-loop; if no argument is provided, run "code2"; all else, run "code3". The following script seems Okay to me, but it got stuck if run without an argument.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f $1 ]; then
  for i in `cat $1`
  do
    <something>
  done
elif [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  "code2"
else
  "code3"
fi
```

Here is the debug output and it got stuck at the end.

```
bash -x myscript
+ '[' -f ']'
++ cat
```

Since I provide no argument, why does it still run into the first if-then flow? I am new to bash scripting. Any help would be thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not quote the variable `"$1"` then it becomes nothing and disappears. The code executed is then (as reported by the shell `-x` option):

```
[ -f ]
```

Which, as `-f` is an string with a length of not zero results in a true test and runs the `then` part.

You need to write (at least):

```
[ -f "$1" ]
```

Which, with an empty argument, will become

```
[ -f "" ]
```

and report a failure to match the `""` file.

One other alternative is to use a parameter expansion (no external quoting needed):

```
[ -f ${1:-""} ]
```

It will expand to `""` if the value of `$1` is null or empty.

And please do not do a for loop to walk the lines of a file. You should consider using a `while read` loop

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f ${1:-""} ]; then
  while read -r line; do
      echo '<something>'
  done <"$1"
elif [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "code2"
else
  echo "code3"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is because with non-existent `$1`, which is also not quoted ( also part of the problem ) the shell treats expression as `[ -f ]` and the `-f` that `[` sees here isn't recognized as flag, but just a single "expression". It's in fact same as:

```
$ [ abracadabra  ] && echo "success"
success
```

And to quote `test` manual (which in case you didn't know is alias for `[` ):

```
   An  omitted  EXPRESSION  defaults  to false.  Otherwise, EXPRESSION is true or false and sets exit
   status.  It is one of:

   ( EXPRESSION )
          EXPRESSION is true
```

Note that if you did quote the expression it would look like so when tracing the output, i.e. it would in fact try to evaluate a null string as existing filename:

```
$ (set -x; [ -f "$this_var_doesnt_exist"  ] && echo "hi" )
+ '[' -f '' ']'
```